# Flask-MySQLdb raises _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: closing a closed connection

Tags: mysql, flask, mysql-python

I'm trying to use Flask-MySQLdb.  Every time I go to a page I get the error `_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: closing a closed connection`.  Why isn't this working?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, json
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

application = Flask(__name__)
mysql = MySQL(application)

application.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
application.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
application.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'db name'
application.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(application)

@application.route('/')
def index():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SHOW TABLES")
    rv= cur.fetchall()
    return str(rv)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've initialize the extension on the same application twice.  Each time it's initialized, it registers a function that closes the connection.  So the second function closes a connection that was already closed by the first registered function.  Either remove `application` from `MySQL` (preferable) or remove the explicit call to `mysql.init_app`.

```
mysql = MySQL()
mysql.init_app(application)
```